# How to enable php 8.0 extensions on windows

Tags: php

Everywhere on the internet says that you should just edit your php.ini file but for some reason, it doesn't exist on 8.0. There are php.ini-development and php.ini-production files but editing them does nothing, at least when I tried to enable the openssl extension. I couldn't find a way around this and could not update nor downgrade my PHP (for unrelated reasons).

Comment: After you install PHP, you are supposed to use those development and production files as a basis to define your own `php.ini` file in any of [the searched directories](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php).  For local development, most people just copy or rename the development file.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a PHP script that just runs `phpinfo();` and it will output a page full of interesting information, including the currently loaded ini file(s). That should tell you which files you need to change to enable specific modules.

Answer (score 1):

Install PHP 8.1 and copy and paste the php.ini (which sometimes appears as php) into your 8.0.
If your 8.1 version of php doesn't have a php.ini, look for a file of file type of configuration settings named PHP.

This solution is for people unwilling or unable to upgrade to their php.

Comment: Also had on my folder two files: php.ini-development and php.ini-production. Just grab any and copy it with a name php.ini and php should pick it up. Just checkout which best fits your needs